# Unity3d NullReferenceException

Tags: unity3d

Сделал аудиоменеджер для воспроизведения музыки на фоне игры, всё работает но при попытке остановить воспроизведение выдаёт NullReferenceException. Объект со скриптом AudioManager.cs находится во всех сценах, во всех сценах музыка воспроизводиться и продолжается корректно, но, как я уже сказал при добавлении строчки FindObjectOfType().StopPlaying("Theme"); получаю NullReferenceException.  Хочу добиться возможности выключать определённую тему в сцене, и включать другую.
Файл AudioManager.cs

```
 using UnityEngine.Audio;
 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
   public Sound[] sounds;

public static AudioManager instance;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = this;
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    foreach(Sound s in sounds)
    {
        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.clip = s.clip;

        s.source.volume = s.volume;
        s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
        s.source.loop = s.loop;
    }
}

void Start()
{
        Play("Theme");
}

public void Play(string name)
{
    Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);

    s.source.Play();
}

public void StopPlaying(string name)
{
    Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
    if (s == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Sound: " + name + " not found!");
        return;
    }

    s.source.Stop();// первая строчка, указанная в отладчике
}
}
```

Файл PasswordScript.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PasswordScript : MonoBehaviour

(объявления полей, не связанных со звуком)
void Start()
{
     FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().StopPlaying("Theme"); //вторая строчка, указанная в отладчике
 Дописывать метод, из соображений экономии места, не стану
```

Comment: А зачем ты устраиваешь поиск, если есть статическая ссылка `AudioManager.instance`?

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужно получить доступ по ссылке:

```
AudioManager.instance.StopPlaying("Theme");
```